# CSS - Bootstrap Auto padding?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to style a webpage using Bootstrap. Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="mycolumn" id="sidebar">

            <div class="list-group">
                    <div class="list-group-item"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
                    <div id="mainmenucontentdiv" class="list-group-item">
                        <div>
                            <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Temporibus sit</a>
                            <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Deserunt consequuntur</a>
                            <a class="list-group-item" href="#">magni nesciunt</a>
                            <a class="list-group-item" href="#">lorem bla </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>

            <div id="contentarea" class="mycolumn">
                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero molestiae ipsam fuga excepturi, ullam illum iste non culpa et beatae, aut, cupiditate vitae voluptatibus explicabo magni tempora impedit saepe inventore.</div>
           </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar{
    background-color: red;
    padding: 20px 0px 0px;
    width: 250px;
}
.mycolumn{
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
#mainmenucontentdiv {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}
.table-row{
    display: table-row;
}
```

To better view the example, you may see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/pkctb8uc/

Why is that the content in `#contentarea` is pushed down? As you can see there is a big blank area at the top. How can I fix it?

Comment: I am not seeing black area ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you use display: table-cell, to fix this just add "vertical-align: top" in .mycolumn

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it solved my problem. Curious, as the contentarea is fill with content, why is it still appear blank at the top?

Answer (score 0):

Edit css as follows ,

```
.mycolumn{
  float: left;
position: relative;
display: table-cell;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-bottom: 3px;
padding-top: 16px;
width: 37%;
}
```